# lightbox, tool tips not working with foundation

Tags: tooltip, zurb-foundation, lightbox

I applied foundation.css to make my site responsive. But after that tool tips, light box is not working. Fonts are getting larger. Where should I correct in my custom.css or foundation.css

[Tool tip not working in this site](http://www.egtours.com)

```css
html {
 height: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 1px;
}

body {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 background-color: #CCCCCC;
 
}

body,
td.sohotext,
td.text,
p,
span {
 font-family: sans-serif, Helvetica, Verdana, Arial;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #525252;
 line-height: 140%; 
}

/* Fixes and hacks */

.clearfix:after {
 clear: both;
 display: block;
 content: ".";
 height: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
}

* html input.quick_signup {
 background-attachment: fixed;
 }

/*END - Fixes and Hacks */


/* Navigation */

#mainnav a:link, #mainnav a:visited  {

 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 padding-right: 13px;
 float: left;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-left: 13px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 background-image: url(images/menu_div.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 background-position: right top;
}


#mainnav a:hover {
 color: #36CC2F;
 background-image: url(images/nav_active.jpg);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 background-position: right top;
 padding:4px 12px 4px;


}

.hmains {
    font-size: 100%;
}
#megamenu {  
        list-style-type:none;  
        width:100%;  
        margin: 3px auto 04px auto;  
        height:40px;  
        padding:2px 0px 3px 0px; 
}
table.vmenu_subs {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
 margin-top: 15px;
}

/*#leftav a:link, #leftnav a:visited, */
   a.vmenu_sub_off:link,
   a.vmenu_sub_off:visited,
   a.vmenu_sub_on:link,
   a.vmenu_sub_on:visited  {
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 95%;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #000;
 background-image: url(images/sideNav_bullet.gif);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: left center;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #acacac;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding-left: 24px;
 display: block;
 width: 150px;
}

/*#leftav a:hover,*/
a.vmenu_sub_off:hover,
a.vmenu_sub_on:hover
a.vmenu_sub_off:active,
a.vmenu_sub_on:active  {
 color: #666;
}


a:link, a:visited {
 color: #00CC00;
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
 color: #009900;
 margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
}

#feat a:link, #feat a:visited {
 color: #fdb417;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#feat a:hover {
 color: #fed27e;
}

/*END - Navigation */

#headwrapper {
 background-image: url(images/top_bg.png);
 background-repeat: 50% no-repeat;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 height: 109px;
 position: relative;
}
#featwrapper {
 background-color: #1e8019;
 height: 124px;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
 border-bottom-width: 1px;
 border-bottom-color: #185d14;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-top-width: 1px;
 border-top-style: solid;
 border-top-color: #2b9d22;
}
#feat {
 max-width: 880px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 background-image: url(images/feat_bg.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: left top;
 height: 124px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
#navwrapper {
 background-color: #1e8019;
 height: 32px;
 border-top-width: 1px;
 border-bottom-width: 1px;
 border-top-style: solid;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
 border-top-color: #2b9d22;
 border-bottom-color: #185d14;
}
#nav {
 background-image: url(images/nav_bg.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: left top;
 height: 32px;
 max-width:880px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
#contentwrapper {
 background-color: #ededf1;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
#maincontent {
 background-image: url(images/content_bg.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: left top;
 max-width: 880px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 background-color: #ededf1;
}
#mainnav {
 width: 72%;
 float: left;
 padding-left: 5px;
}
#signup {
 width: 25%;
 padding-left: 5px;
 float: left;
 height: 20px;
 padding-top: 2px;
 font-size: 85%;
 color: #cccccc;
 text-align: center;
}

#subnav {
 margin: 0px;
 float: left;
 min-width:155px;
 width: 25%;
 padding-top: 15px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 padding-left: 5px;

}
#belowmenu {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 210px;
 padding-top: 15px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 
}
div.sidebox {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 210px;
}

#content {
 margin: 0px;
 width: 70%;
 float: left;
 padding-top: 12px;
 padding-right: 7px;
 padding-bottom: 12px;
 padding-left: 7px;
 overflow: visible;
}
#date {
 font-size: 90%;
 text-align: right;
 color: #858585;
}

#featleft {
 float: left;
 width: 25%;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-top: 5px;
}
#featright {
 float: left;
 width: 72%;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-top: 5px;
}

#footer {
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 padding-top: 10px;
 font-size: 85%;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 color: #939393;
}

#head {
 height: 109px;
 max-width: 880px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
}
#logo_box {
 height: 109px;
 float: left;
 width: 28%;
}
#tagline {
 float: left;
 width: 70%;
 color: #999999;
 text-align: right;
 padding-top: 22px;
}

#logo {
 position: absolute;
 top: 3px;
}


#trimbar {
 background-color: #000000;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 7px;
 width: 100%;
 border-top: 1px solid #999999;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
}

div.newsbox {
    line-height: 115%;
}

/*hiding from IE mac \*/

* html .clearfix {
 height: 1%;
}

.clearfix {
    display: block;
}

/* end hiding from IE mac */


#footerwrapper {
 width: 100%;
 border-top-width: 2px;
 border-top-style: solid;
 border-top-color: #959595;
 background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
/* Integrated Styles */

.portfolio {
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
}

span.alert, 
span.profile,
span.download,
span.search  {
 display: block;
    float: left;
 margin:  10px;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 45px;
}

span.alert {
 color: #333333;
 background-color: #dddddd;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #b6b6b6;
 border-top: 4px solid #b6b6b6;
 background-image: url(images/span_alert.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 7px 12px;
}

span.profile {
 color: #333333;
 background-color: #dddddd;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #b6b6b6;
 border-top: 4px solid #b6b6b6;
 background-image: url(images/span_profile.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 7px 12px;
}

span.download {
    width: 100%; 
 color: #333333;
 background-color: #dddddd;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #b6b6b6;
 border-top: 4px solid #b6b6b6;
 background-image: url(images/span_download.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 7px 12px;
}

span.search {
 color: #333333;
 background-color: #dddddd;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #b6b6b6;
 border-top: 4px solid #b6b6b6;
 background-image: url(images/span_search.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 7px 12px;
}

span.product {
 color: #333333;
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #b6b6b6;
 margin:  10px;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 10px;
 line-height: 145%;
 display: block;
}

blockquote {
 border-top: 4px solid #D3D3D3;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #D3D3D3;
 margin:  10px;
 padding: 10px 10px 5px 45px;
 background-color: #f5f5f5;
 background-image: url(images/quote1.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 5px 5px;
}

blockquote p {
 padding-right: 35px;
 background-image: url(images/quote2.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 100% 100%;
}
ul
{
list-style-type:none;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
ul li { 
        background-image: url("images/li_bullet.gif");
        background-position: 0px 4px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        overflow: hidden;/* added by dsonesuk as li cannot detect area of    floated 'a' elements*/
        padding-left: 14px;
        margin-left: 0px 4px;
        font-size: 12px;
}
 
ul, li {list-style-type:none !important;}
}

h4 {
 font-size: 115%;
 color: #333;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#feat h4 {
 color: #fdb417;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 120%;
 color: #0066FF
}


h3 {
 font-size: 150%;
 color: #1E7D19;
}

h2 {
 font-size: 180%;
 color: #196115;
}
input.login_box {
 border: 0;
 height: 25px;
 width: 122px;
 padding-left: 30px;
 padding-top: 4px;
 background-image: url(images/login_bg.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: left top;
}

input.pass_box {
 border: 0;
 height: 25px;
 width: 122px;
 padding-left: 30px;
 padding-top: 4px;
 background-image: url(images/password_bg.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: left top;
}

input.quick_signup {
 border: 0;
 height: 19px;
 width: 168px;
 padding-left: 32px;
 padding-top: 3px;
 margin-top: 4px;
 background-image: url(images/quick_signup_bg.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: left top;
 background-color: #ededed;
}

div#answer0,
div#answer1,
div#answer2,
div#answer3,
div#answer4,
div#answer5,
div#answer6,
div#answer7,
div#answer8,
div#answer9,
div#answer10 

{
        padding-left: 28px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 background-image: url(images/answer.gif);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 2px 0;
}

table#Search_Form,
table#Search_Form2  {
    
}

table#Detail_Results2,
table#Initial_Results {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.MegaMenu {
display:table;
margin: 0 auto !important;
height:29px;
background-color:transparent;

}

#mainnav table, #mainnav table tr th, #mainnav table tr td, #Container td {
 padding: 0px!important;
background:inherit!important;
}

#Container,.MegaMenuTable, .MegaMenuTable tr {
background:inherit!important;
}
table {
border-width:0px;
background:inherit;
}
table tr th, table tr td {
padding:inherit;
}
table tr.even, table tr.alt, table tr:nth-of-type(2n) {
background:inherit;
}
.sohotext p {
min-width:120px;
}
#tagline {
    bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
 width:62%;
}
#tagline img {
margin: 0px 0px -12px; 
height: auto!important; 
max-width: 100%; 
width: auto!important; 
max-height: 68px;
min-height:45px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>#title#</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sohoadmin/program/modules/site_templates/pages/PHASE2-Dinkin_Flicka-Evergreencss/css/foundation.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sohoadmin/program/modules/site_templates/pages/PHASE2-Dinkin_Flicka-Evergreen/custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tooltip/themes/2/tooltip.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lightbox/css/lightbox.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jsimgslider/themes/8/js-image-slider.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mactabs/mctabs.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.egtours.com/tooltip/themes/2/tooltip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://www.egtours.com/sohoadmin/plugins/MegaMenuBuilder/javascripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="http://www.egtours.com/jsimgslider/themes/8/mcVideoPlugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.egtours.com/jsimgslider/themes/8/js-image-slider.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.egtours.com/float-panel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.egtours.com/mactabs/javascript-tabs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.egtours.com/motionpack.js"></script>

    <script src="sohoadmin/program/modules/site_templates/pages/PHASE2-Dinkin_Flicka-Evergreencss/js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
<body onload="slidedown('featwrapper');">
<div id="headwrapper">
<div id="head" class="clearfix">
<div id="logo_box"><a href="../../../../../../../Home_Page.php"><img id="logo" border="0" alt="Home" width="322" height="118" src="images/_userimg-logo.png" /></a></div>
<div id="tagline"><img border="0" alt="Home" width="468" height="60" src="images/_userimg-ad_banner.png" /></div></div></div>
<div id="trimbar"></div>
<div id="featwrapper" style="display: none; height: 124px; overflow: hidden">
<div id="feat" class="clearfix">
<div id="featleft">#NEWSBOX#</div>
<div id="featright">#PROMOTXT1#</div></div></div>
<div id="navwrapper">
<div id="nav" class="clearfix">
<div id="signup"><a href="javascript:;" onmousedown="toggleSlide('featwrapper');"><img style="border: 0pt" border="0" alt="Toggle the banner up or down" width="110" height="27" src="images/hide-show.png" /></a></div>
<div id="mainnav">#MEGAMENU#</div></div></div>
<div id="contentwrapper">
<div id="maincontent" class="clearfix">
<div id="subnav">#VSUBS#
<div id="belowmenu">#POWERPLUG4#</div></div>
<div id="content">
<div id="date">#AUTODATESTAMP#</div>#CONTENT#</div></div>
<div id="footerwrapper">#COPYRIGHT#<div id="footer">
<table id="table1" border="0" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="7" align="left">
<p align="center"><a title="" href="../../../../../../../Our_Policies.php">Our Policies</a>| <a href="../../../../../../../Privacy_Statement.php">Privacy Statement</a></p></td></tr>
<td width="60"><img border="0" alt="coat of arm" width="66" height="56" src="../../../../../../../images/logos/coatofarm.png" /></td>
<td width="152"><img border="0" alt="natta logo" width="53" height="56" src="../../../../../../../images/logos/nattalogo.png" /></td>
<td width="55"><img border="0" alt="uftaa logo" width="80" height="56" src="../../../../../../../images/logos/uftaa.png" /></td>
<td width="71"><img title="" alt="skull logo" width="75" height="36" src="../../../../../../../images/paybyskull.png" /><br />
</td>
<td width="71">
<p><img title="" alt="paypal logo" width="57" height="57" src="../../../../../../../images/paypalv.png" /></p></td>
<td width="26">
<p><img title="" alt="vitof logo" width="97" height="73" src="../../../../../../../images/vitof_logo.png" /></p></td>
<td width="90"><img border="0" alt="SSL" width="90" height="50" src="http://www.egtours.com/images/rapidssl_ssl_certificate.gif" /></td></tbody></table></div></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.egtours.com/lightbox/js/lightbox.js"></script>
<div id="backtop">&#9650;</div>
#jquery#
<script>
    /* Remove the slogan div cleanly if it's not in use */
   $(function () {
   if($(".slogan").html().length === 0) {
    $(".slogan").remove();
   }
   /* Expand the content area out if the sidebar isn't in use */
   if (!$("#box-one").text().trim().length){
  $(".middle").addClass("large-12").removeClass("large-8");
  $(".box").remove();
  }
  });
</script>
   <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     $(document).foundation();
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your path's to *foundation.tooltip.js* and to *foundation1.css* are incorrect and they are not loading, therefore no tooltips. If you want your own custom.css file to override any of foundation's css, it needs to load after foundation1.css.